# Running a script using subproccess.call loses all export info

Tags: python

If I run my script using

```
subprocess.call(["bash", "-c", "" + "  nohup python3 myStuff.py > /dev/null 2>&1&"])
```

All the `export <my_credential>` that I run in terminal is lost for `myStuff.py`.

Is there a way to keep the exports when I spawn subprocess?

Comment: That's not true. `subprocess.call` does not drop environment variables.

Comment: BTW, this code is doing a whole lot of work for no purpose. `nohup` is completely unnecessary here -- almost all it does is redirecting stdin, stdout and stderr when they're pointed at the terminal, and you're already doing 2/3rds of that yourself. `subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'myStuff.py', stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)` and there you are -- no `bash`, no `nohup`, and because you switched from `call` to `Popen` you don't need the `&` either.

Comment: Anyhow -- I'd suggest looking at hew you're _starting_ your Python script. Are you actually starting it from your terminal, or from a GUI or IDE or such? Check whether the environment variables are in the Python script's `os.environ` -- not the new script you're starting, but the one you're calling `subprocess.call` in. If the variables aren't present there, fix that _first_, before you investigate the child.